# Initialization of local sync store in Azure's offline-sync API

Tags: sqlite, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm working with Azure's offline-sync API.

(It's REALLY GREAT so far, but since it's still new-ish it doesn't have comprehensive documentation, only tutorials. We need to craft dependable integration tests, and we're finding that tricky because we need to rely on published behavior in official docs for that... or dig into the source, but that is liable to change at any time.)

The samples do this:

```
var store = new MobileServiceSQLiteStore("localstore.db");
```

The comments mention "initializes local store".

I assume the local sync database is a "throw-away" asset, as it can be recreated at will.

*Is the expected behavior that it will create the local SQLite file if it does not exist, or it will recreate the file each time the mobile app starts and that call is made?*

Comment: This is unclear [because the tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-offline-data/#review-the-client-sync-code) says "...This *creates a new* local SQLite database using the..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorials are augmented by the HOWTO documentation (available under Mobile > Develop - in the same area as the tutorials) and the GitHub Wiki and the github.io pages for the SDK.

The local store is created if it doesn't exist, and new fields are added to tables if they are needed.  It's sometimes good to delete the database - for example, if you reduce the field count in your mobile app (the process only adds fields).  If you do this, the database will be re-created when the app is next restarted.

Comment: See also: [How to use the managed client for Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library/) and [Azure Mobile Client API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt419521(v=azure.10).aspx)

Comment: Didn't see some of those links, thanks guys! They will come in very handy... BTW the "published docs" I referred to where official MSDN documentation, like in @lindydonna-msft's comment.

Comment: To anyone with the same issue (docs-wise), I found [another cool link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/learning-paths/appservice-mobileapps/) which categorises the SDK's into various feature sets.